# Compser network upgrade successfully, but no new features found in composer-rest-api

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

There are two channels in my bc, and I deployed networks in each of them, in one channel,I have start a network which named `'compound-network'`, and have a assest named `compound`, attributes are:

```
asset Compound identified by compoundId {
  o String compoundId
  o String name
  o String smiles
  o String source
  o String location
  --> CompoundParticipant owner
}
```

the composer-rest-api shows:
[image]

but when I add a attribute cas,like:

```
asset Compound identified by compoundId {
  o String compoundId
  o String name
  o String smiles
  o String cas
  o String source
  o String location
  --> CompoundParticipant owner
}
```

the composer-rest-api didn't shows the new attribute, meanwhile I found the chaincode have upgrade from version 0.0.2 to 0.0.3.
**And I found the `cas` attribute is in my bna file**

I use the command `'composer upgrade'`

I was confused, in my previous experience, I deployed two networks in one channel , and all of them works fine

Comment: The attribute `cas` apeared in the `compound` asset after serval minutes... , this is very strange..I didn't do anything about the network

Comment: Maybe the browser was caching the old explorer page and it expired and reloaded ?

Comment: Yes, I restart the browser and I cleared all cache, maybe I restarted the rest-api, so the new feature comes up

Comment: Yes, you must restart the rest-server

Answer (score 1):

Have you stopped and re-started the REST server after upgrading the Business Network?

The first thing the REST server does when it starts is to 'Discover' the network and build the REST endpoints - you have probably seen this in the output when it starts.

So when you upgrade the Business Network, the REST server needs a restart to re-Discover the network with the changes you have made.

You should also be aware that when you change the model your existing data does not match the model and so it 'disappears' !  With new fields you can create as Optional and the existing data won't 'disappear'.  There are more details on 'migrating' data and changing models in the [Composer Knowledge Wiki](https://github.com/hyperledger/composer-knowledge-wiki/blob/latest/knowledge.md#migration)

Comment: Yes, I restart the composer-rest-api ! Maybe that's the reason why it appeared finally.Thank you very much!